# Term for writing a number as "five" vs "5"?

Tags: vocabulary, numbers

What I mean is, if I said "Write the number **_** ", then you would write "5", "27", etc.

Whereas if I said instead "Write the number **_** ", then you would write "five", "twenty-seven", etc.

I'm not just looking for the oft-used expression "write it out"....I'm wondering if there are proper terms for these two options, possibly obvious ones I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You write the number *in numerals* or *in words*. Synonyms for the latter include *spell out* or *write out*.

Comment: To expand on this you could say "five was written alphabetically or numerically".

Comment: @Ste The word "alphabetically" means something different. It's not appropriate in this context.

Answer (score 7):

One could *spell out* the numbers:

> [spell out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spell%20out): 2. to write or print in letters and in full

[Both AP and Chicago](http://www.apvschicago.com/2011/05/numbers-spell-out-or-use-numerals.html) appear to use this terminology, as does [MLA](http://www.docstyles.com/mlacrib.htm#Sec33). This means more or less the same thing as *write out*, but if this is insufficiently specific for you, you could simply say to *write numbers using words* or to *write numbers out longhand*, with the additional caveat that *longhand* in research means the full number as opposed to its scientific notation (e.g. *25000000* instead of *2.5 × 10<sup>7</sup>*).

When we express a number using figures, we write with *numerals*.

> [numeral](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/numeral): a sign or symbol that represents a number.

If you want to be even more specific, you can specify the type of numerals: [Egyptian](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Egyptian_numerals.html), [Mayan](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ChronologicalInterpretationOfMayanNumerals/), [Babylonian](http://cs-exhibitions.uni-klu.ac.at/index.php?id=323), and so on, though the only systems commonly used in primarily English-speaking countries are "[Arabic](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/22599/22599-h/22599-h.htm)" numerals (actually Indian in origin, but commonly known as *Arabic*) and [Roman numerals](http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/roman/).

Alternatively, you can specify that it be written using *digits*, or *[numerical digits](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121387/what-is-a-numeric-digit)* if there could be confusion about the type of *digit* in use.