# What is the term for representing whole numbers with integers instead of English words?

Tags: terminology, mathematics

For example, "I am giving you the ___ form". Where I am using numeric characters e.g., `1` instead of `one`. I don't think canonical exactly fits here because the English version is seems to be unique as well.

Comment: Well, they're generally referred to as "Arabic numerals".

Comment: You're using digits, but unfortunately, _digital_ now has a quite different meaning to most people.

Comment: You'd use an ordinal (first / 1st) rather than a cardinal (one / 1) number before the noun.

Comment: Converse question: *[Term for writing a number as “five” vs “5”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142026)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am giving you the **numeric** form